# React Native Component Hide with Keyboard

Tags: react-native, view, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, tpkeyboardavoiding

I create `Header` and `Gifted Chat` in `React Native`.

```js
return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
            <StatusBar
                backgroundColor="#4A43EC"
                barStyle="light-content"
            />
            {/* Header */}
            <KeyboardAvoidingView >
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', paddingVertical: 16, backgroundColor: '#4A43EC',}}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 24, }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
                        <Image
                            style={{ height: 22, width: 22, marginRight: 13 }}
                            source={require("../Assets/Icons/EventDetailsLeftArrow.png")}
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 24, fontWeight: '400', }}>{item.name} Id: {item.id}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            {/* Body */}
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <GiftedChat
                    messages={messages}
                    onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
                    user={{
                        _id: rid,
                    }}
                    alwaysShowSend
                    renderBubble={renderBubble}
                // renderSend={renderSend}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    )
```

When I open `Keyboard` for typing, the `Header` hide.

I don't want this, I want that `header` to be always show while typing.

Answer (score 1):

It behaves in this manner because your header is wrapped in KeyboardAvoidingView remove it and it will work normally.

Your chat component should be wrapped in KeyboardAvoidingView.

Answer (score 1):

Take your `header` bar from the `scrollview` and use `KeyboardAwareScrollView` instead of KeyboardAvoidingView

KeyboardAwareScrollView handles both scroll and keyboard behavior. KeyboardAvoidingView should only be used on screens where the user shouldn't scroll.

Example:

KeyboardAwareScrollView.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view'
    export const KeyboardAvoidingView = (props: any) => {
      const defaultProps = {
        style: { flex: 1 },
        contentContainerStyle: { flexGrow: 1 },
        bounces: false,
        bouncesZoom: false,
        alwaysBounceVertical: false,
        alwaysBounceHorizontal: false,
    
      };
    
      return React.createElement(KeyboardAwareScrollView, {
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps: 'handled',
        enableOnAndroid: true,
        ...defaultProps,
        ...props,
      });
    };
```

import {
ImageBackground,
TextInput,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import KeyboardAvoidingView from './keyboardAvoidingView'

Usage

```
 const Issue = () => {
      return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
        <Header/>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView>
         <ImageBackground
            source={{
              uri: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613828330596-982c62f72e9a?q=80&w=2670&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D",
            }}
            style={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1 }}>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                height: 40,
                margin: 12,
                borderWidth: 1,
                padding: 10,
              }}
            ></TextInput>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </SafeAreaView>
      );
    };
    
    export default Issue;
```

Answer (score 1):

To keep the header always visible when the keyboard is open, you can adjust your code to use the `KeyboardAvoidingView` with the behavior set to padding and make sure the flex property is set to 1 for both the `KeyboardAvoidingView and the parent View. This will ensure that the header remains visible when the keyboard is open.

```
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
    <StatusBar backgroundColor="#4A43EC" barStyle="light-content"/>
    
    {/* Header */}
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', width: '100%', paddingVertical: 16, backgroundColor: '#4A43EC' }}>
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: 24 }}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}>
            <Image style={{ height: 22, width: 22, marginRight: 13 }} source={require("../Assets/Icons/EventDetailsLeftArrow.png")} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{ color: '#fff', fontSize: 24, fontWeight: '400' }}>{item.name} Id: {item.id}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    {/* Body */}
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <GiftedChat messages={messages} onSend={messages => onSend(messages)} user={{ _id: rid }} alwaysShowSend renderBubble={renderBubble} />
    </View>
  </View>
);
```